# Powershell function behavior in PowerShell ISE

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I am trying to run some pretty basic powershell code: a function with some tests on two input parameters: $Location and $Algo

Here is my simplified code:

```
Function Get-Test ($Location,$Algo)
{
# Test if the function is called with input parameters or requests default parameters
echo "INPUT"
echo $Location
echo $Algo
  if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Algo))
  {
  $UR2 = "UR2 DEFAUT"
  $UR4 = "UR4 DEFAUT"
  }
  Else
  {
  $UR2 = $Location
  $UR4 = $Aglo
  }
  echo "OUTPUT"
  echo $UR2
  echo $UR4
  echo "Why $ UR4 is EMPTY WHEN THERE IS NO DEFAULT VALUE ???"
}
```

When I run this code, with input on $Algo, my first "echo $Algo" is what I expect, but the second $UR4 echo is empty.

I am probably missing something stupid...

Philippe

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: `$Algo` is not the same as `$Aglo`. You have a typo `$UR4 = $Aglo`

Comment: Nice catch of $Aglo and $Algo !!!

Comment: Thanks a million !!! I broke down my code to this little piece for 3 hours today, not seeing the character inversion :-) !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks fine to me.

But in PowerShell, the variable delimiter calling a function is a whitsepace and not a comma. Maybe that's what you're missing.

Call the function like this:

```
Get-Test "MyLocation" "MyAlgo"
```